# azure b2c login with facebook redirect to oauth2/authresp url

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, facebook-login

I am using standard sign-in/sign-up user-flows provided by azure. and have added Facebook login as an identity provider.
Everything works fine till i am authenticated by Facebook. Once I am authenticated, I am redirect to https://<domain.name>.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
and on this page, it shows the below page instead of getting me logged-in.

[image]

trying to figure out how could I skip this step.
Any pointer/help will be apricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2C does this for social providers (and federation) because the first and last name may not be passed in the JWT and it needs something to "name" the user.

Essentially, it's a ProfileEdit.

In custom policies, you can delete the step from the user journey.

Comment: I am going to try with custom policy, if you have points please do let me know.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/removing-the-profile-edit-screen-with-azure-ad-b2c-social-or-federation-connections-58da453a25f4

Comment: i was able to skip the step with the above link. Thank you @rbrayb. but in custom policy, I dont get back oid in the claims. tried adding to OpendID technical profile not use.

Comment: Could you provide the full solution, not scraps?